# DB schema for storing temperature sensor data from different recorders - 1 or many tables needed?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm trying to get my head around the following problem:

I have 4 Temperature recorders that will be sending measurements over to my server.
The interval is 1 set of data per minute. Each recorder is only working for about 3 to 4 days per month and has 6, 12 or 18 sensors depending on the type of recorder. How can I best store these readings?

I was thinking of making 1 table for all the measurements each recorder and a separate table that list the data about the recorder. This way I don't end up with allot of empty fields.

Any thoughts?

Table name = **measurements_recorder_3**

| Id | TC-1 | ... | TC-6 | Timestamp | Recorder_Id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 53 | 248,5 | ... | 255,9 | 2021-05-10 16:33:45 | 3 |
| 54 | 248,8 | ... | 256,5 | 2021-05-10 16:34:45 | 3 |
| 55 | 249,3 | ... | 257,2 | 2021-05-10 16:35:45 | 3 |

Table name = **recorders**

| Id | Name | Location | Description | ... | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | REC6003 | 50KVA008 | 6-TC recorder in mobile 50KVA unit | ... | 2018-09-15 11:38:05 |
| 4 | REC18002 | REC18002 | 18-TC recorder in a standalone case | ... | 2019-02-14 16:12:59 |

Comment: Can a recorder move over time, and would this occur without renaming it?

Comment: What SELECTs might you use against the table(s).

Comment: @bbaird The location is a reference to equipment it is built into. So the equipment can move to different Geo-locations/project sites but the recorder remains in the same built in location. The name of the recorder is a fixed value, unique and not reuseable.

Comment: @RickJames Mostly something like last entry, entries between certain dates, very basic stuff.

Comment: @vennot_be Before I write the answer, would this be accurate: `Equipment` contains one-to-many `Recorder`. `Recorder` has one-to-many `Sensor`.  `Sensor` records zero-to-many `Measurement`?

Comment: @bbaird that is correct. But for the moment 'Equipment' 'Recorder' rellation is a one-to-one.  Maby one-to-many is more future proof.

Comment: @bbaird - Need more specifics.  For example:  "Last entry in the table" is easy.  "Last entry for each recorder is messier".

Comment: @bbaird - Anyway, one way to answer your own question is to write out the `SELECTs` for _both_ schema designs.  That may make it obvious which design is better.

Comment: @bbaird - One-to-many should always be implemented with two tables.  Zero-to-many is implemented the same way.  Doesn't this answer all your questions?

Comment: @vennot_be One final question - do the `Sensors` record independently, or does each `Recorder` collect data for all `Sensors` at once?

Comment: @bbaird the recorder collects all the sensor data and pushes it towards the DB in one push per minute. So if 4 of the 6 sensors on that recorder are working you will get a record with 4 values and 2 null values.  There is no need to combine the measurements of 2 recorders in 1 query.